# I want to print my all excel data in new tkinter window using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like print all the information present in the excel data in new tkinter window

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tkinter's grid.
For example,  to create a simple excel-like table:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

height = 5
width = 5
for i in range(height): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        b = Entry(root, text="")
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)

mainloop()
```

To print, consider the following example in which I  make a button with Tkinter that gets some text from a widget and then prints it to console using the print() function.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def print_text(*args):
    try:
        print(text1.get())
    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Little tkinter app for printing")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N,W,E,S))

mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

text1 = StringVar()
text_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 20, textvariable=text1)
text_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = (N,W,E,S))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Print!", command =
           print_text(text1)).grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky = (E))

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx = 5, pady = 5)

text_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', print_text)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For unlimited data how can i print